# PIP - How to install dependencies from local folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install dependencies via pip from a local folder. My `requirements.txt` looks like below

```
--no-index

retrying==1.3.3
six==1.11.0
```

The steps I followed

```
support@vrni-platform:~$ mkdir app_depen
support@vrni-platform:~$ sudo pip install --download=/home/support/app_depen retrying==1.3.3
```

The content of `/home/support/app_depen`

```
support@vrni-platform:~$ ls -lah /home/support/app_depen/
total 32K
drwxrwx--- 2 support support 4.0K Sep 15 15:04 .
drwx------ 5 support support 4.0K Sep 15 15:09 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root    root     11K Sep 15 15:04 retrying-1.3.3.tar.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root    root     11K Sep 15 15:04 six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Then on trying to do the install via pip as shown below

`support@vrni-platform:~$ sudo pip install -U --force-reinstall --allow-unverified --find-links=/home/support/app_depen/ -r requirements.txt`

I am getting the below error

```
Collecting retrying==1.3.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement retrying==1.3.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for retrying==1.3.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

I tried changing the permission like below. But still getting the same error

```
support@vrni-platform:~$ ls -lah /home/support/app_depen/
total 32K
drwxrwx--- 2 support support 4.0K Sep 15 15:04 .
drwx------ 5 support support 4.0K Sep 15 15:09 ..
-rw-r-xr-x 1 root    root     11K Sep 15 15:04 retrying-1.3.3.tar.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root    root     11K Sep 15 15:04 six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

- Python - 2.7.6
- PIP - 7.1.2

Comment: Did you try upgrading pip?

Comment: No at the moment we cannot do it in our environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the `--find-links` inside the `requirements.txt` like below and then executing `sudo pip install -U -r requirements.txt` worked for me.

```
--no-index
--find-links /home/support/app_depen

retrying==1.3.3
six==1.11.0
```